# Moment generating function (multivariate case).

Tags: probability-theory

I only studied these concepts with respect to the univariate case, can someone confirm that the following holds for random vectors (a reference would be appreciated)?

Definition:

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and a number $\delta>0$, if $M_{(X,Y)}(s,t):=E[e^{sX+tY}]<\infty$ for $∥(s,t)∥<\delta$, we say that the random vector $(X,Y)$ admits moment generating function (M.G.F.) $M_{(X,Y)}$.

Analycity Theorem:

The M.G.F. of the previous definition is analytic in $(0,0)$ and
$∥(s,t)∥ < δ ⇒ M_{(X,Y)}(s,t) = \sum_{j\geq0,k\geq0}E[X^jX^k]s^jt^k/(j!k!) ⇒ \frac{\partial^{j+k}}{\partial^j\partial^k}M_{X,Y}(0,0)=E[X^jX^k]$.

Uniqueness Theorem:

If exists $δ > 0$ such that $ ∥(s,t)∥ < δ ⇒ M_{(X_1,Y_1)}(s,t) = M_{(X_2,Y_2)}(s,t)$, then $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ have the same (joint) distribution (i.e. $F_{(X_1,Y_1)} = F_{(X_2,Y_2)}$).

Continuity Theorem:

Given the random vectors $(X,Y), (X_1,Y_1), (X_2,Y_2), …$, with M.G.F. respectively $M_{(X,Y)}, M_{(X_1,Y_1)}, M_{(X_2,Y_2)}, …$; if exists $δ > 0$ such that
$∥(s,t)∥ < δ ⇒ lim_nM_{(X_n,Y_n)}(s,t) = M_{(X,Y)}(s,t)$, then $lim_nF_{(X_n,Y_n)} = F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$.